# Determine field names corresponding to ALV output columns

Tags: abap, alv

I'm working on a huge, already existing report which uses ALV grid for outputting the data. I now need to rename some columns, because of some trouble with duplicate heading texts.

Is there a way to determine which column in the output corresponds to which field of the data? The columns that need some work mostly are currency or weight units, so the only output they give for each row is "USD" or "kg" for example, which makes it fairly hard in debugging to find the right one since there are multiple of them in the output.

Comment: You can find field name by Press F1 in the output of ALV cell and then try to find same field name in the ABAP code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the button to manage the layout variants:

[image]

Click the button Show technical field names :

[image]

Click the button Hide technical field names to display the texts again :

[image]

It's better to copy & paste the whole lists in a dedicated spreadsheet/table view software, to see directly both heading texts and technical names, and "transpose" them from vertical to horizontal so that you see the same layout as in the ALV.